# Qml FileDialog is rendering behind main window with QQuickWidget (QT 5.9.1)

Tags: qt, qml, qmainwindow, qquickwidget

I am building a desktop application using *QML* with *QQuickWidget* and *QMainWindow*, everything looks work fine except to the *FileDialog*. When I open a window using *FileDialog* it works flawlessly at first time but in the second time and so on the *FileDialog* window is rendered behind the main window, preventing the user to choose a file, it is just possible to choose a file after click on the "choose window" (that bring it forward). If the application is in fullscreen mode it is not possible to realize that the *FileDialog* window is opened.
It just happen when I use *QQuickWidget* and *QMainWindow*, if I create a project with *QGuiApplication* (without *QQuickWidget* and *QMainWindow*) I don't have any problems with *FileDialog* behavior. Some idea how can I make *FileDialog* work properly with *QQuickWidget*?

FileDialog code:

```
/*uncomment ApplicationWindow and comment the rectangle component to right behavior*/
/*
ApplicationWindow{
height: 600
width: 800 
*/

Rectangle {
id: rect
visible: true

Button{
    id:open
    height: 40
    onClicked: fileDialog.open()
    text: "open dialog"
}

FileDialog {

    id: fileDialog
    modality: Qt.ApplicationModal
    title: "FileDialogTest"
    nameFilters: [ "Zip Files (*.zip )", "All files (*)" ]
    selectedNameFilter: "All files (*)"
    selectFolder: false
    onAccepted: {
        console.log("Accepted")
    }
    onRejected: {
        console.log("Rejected")
    }
}
//}
```

Main.cpp

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
 /*##### This block make fileDialog work properly #####*/

 /*
 QCoreApplication::setAttribute(Qt::AA_EnableHighDpiScaling);
 QGuiApplication app(argc, argv);

 QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
 engine.load(QUrl(QLatin1String("qrc:/main.qml")));
 if (engine.rootObjects().isEmpty())
     return -1;
 */


 /*#### This block make openDialog work have weird behavior ####*/
 /* Should be commented when the previous block is uncomment */

 QApplication app(argc, argv);
 QMainWindow mainWindow;
 QQuickWidget *quickWidget = new QQuickWidget;
 quickWidget->setMinimumSize(800, 600);
 quickWidget->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);

 quickWidget->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/main.qml"));
 mainWindow.setCentralWidget(quickWidget);
 mainWindow.show();

 return app.exec();
}
```

I made a simple example of my problems it can be download by  https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B_qtSZnigrLtDMHS0-84mOrFe5t2ZVIj/view?usp=sharing and can be run on QtCreator to illustrate my problem.

Comment: you could provide a [mcve] of your problem, currently it is not. It is also necessary that you place in the example code the following instruction: `Controller* controller = Controller::createInstance();
controller->qmlRegister();`?

Comment: I changed my post and built a example that can be download by link (https://drive.google.com/file/d/1B_qtSZnigrLtDMHS0-84mOrFe5t2ZVIj/view?usp=sharing) This way is possible verify what I said about FileDialog behavior. Thanks

Comment: I'm working on Linux with Qt 5.10.1 and I do not see that problem: https://drive.google.com/file/d/15pOdPKHJQ5NjVtK-zoSuhC50ntSRQgGR/view

Comment: I changed my Qt to 5.10.1 and my example worked too, I tried to migrate my project to Qt 5.10.1 but I got a error with QStringView when I use QDateTime

Comment: QStringView was introduced recently in Qt 5.10, how did you use it in Qt 5.9.1?

Comment: The error says " ‘QStringView’ has not been declared" in Qt/5.10.1/gcc_64/include/QtCore/qdatetime.h:311. Do you have some idea what could it be?

Comment: Like I said I am not using QStringView just QDateTime, I figure out what was the problem, I am using quazip and something in this lib is causing the error in my application when I use Qt 5.10.1, so I removed quazip reference and everything works fine. However now I need to find other lib to replace this one.

Comment: I recommend downloading the quazip source code and recompiling it for Qt 5.10.1, and reporting the problem to that quazip bug.

Comment: I just compiled quazip for Qt5.10.1 and it works correctly.

Comment: I recompiled quazip with Qt5.10.1 and it worked too, thank you a lot for your tips, this solved my problem.